# Google Play Authenticate to complete purchase, multiple accounts

Tags: settings, multi-user, google-settings, google-pay

I'm using a device running Android 8.1. I'm trying to complete a purchase using Google Play where I'm facing a problem while authenticating myself after I selected my payment method. I have 4 Google accounts linked to my device. I wish to use my primary Google account to authenticate myself, yet the Google Play application picks the account I've added most recently (which is my dads').

For a few hours today and last night I have searched the internet and the settings of my phone trying to find out how I can change the account that Google Play requires me to authenticate with, but I couldn't find a solution.

Now I do have the password of the Google account that Google Play prompts me to use (because my dad gave it to me), but I do not want to use that account to authenticate as I want the purcahse to be logged/added to my own (primary) Google account.

How can I modify the behavior of Google Play so that I can choose what account is used to authenticate whilst completing a purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching through the Github issues I found [this issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/2) regarding in-app purchases using Android/Google Play. Neto Martin, developer at Google, states the following regarding multi accounts in combination with the in-app purchases:

> The purchases are always related to the user that was selected on Play Store app when you installed the app.
>   So, if an user A installs the app, all purchases will be done on it's account, even if you have the account selector in your app.

Knowing this I knew the only solution for my problem was to reinstall the app (which was my last resort as I would lose some data), making sure my primary Google account was selected, which fixed the issue for me, the app now prompts me to authenticate using my primary Google account.